# How can I programmatically, reliably, determine whether an email address comes from a university?

Tags: email, email-validation

For the purposes of offering student and faculty discounts, how can I programmatically validate whether an email address is owned by a university?

I'd use `$email =~ /\.edu$/`, but nonUS universities don't limit themselves to `.edu` domains.

E.g. `mail@cs.zu.de`.

I'd perform a SPARQL query, preprocessing the email address into its superdomain (`zu.de`, then searching for `University` objects for which the homepage (`web.zu.de`) superdomain (`zu.de`) matches the email address superdomain, but...

Wikipedia/dbpedia doesn't have an article for each individual university, sometimes less popular uni's are grouped together in a single article.

So I'm left with the choice of maintaining my own database of university email addresses (yuck), or identifying some sort of open database of the same. Are there any?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find a reliable university domain list, you might go with moderation: keep your own database of university domains, and *only if you get an unrecognized domain*, mark it as pending review, and have a real person verify if the domain belongs to a university or not, and then add it to your database as either belonging to a university or not. Then you could pre-populate your database with known universities (according to what you expect from your expected userbase), and blacklist major free email providers (i.e. mark as non-university), so you don't have to verify them one by one.

This approach has the additional benefit that you will end up with a filtered database of university-related email domains, which would be a useful resource which you can then offer as a service.